# Error in navigation after creating new Realm object

Tags: android, react-native, navigation, realm, react-native-navigation

I'm using the react-native-navigation package as well as Realm in my project. My app has a realm object called `Notebook` that contains a list of `Verse` objects, which are another realm object.

The structure of the app is very simple, the first page shows a list of `Notebook`s and when one is selected, the app transitions to the second screen which is a list of `Verse`s.

Here is my code to navigate from the notebook list to the verse list:

```
this.props.navigator.push({
  screen: 'com.beyersapps.biblebinderrn.verselist',
  title: notebook.name,
  passProps: {notebook: notebook},
  animated: true,
  animationType: 'fade',
  backButtonTitle: undefined,
  backButtonHidden: false
})
```

This navigation works fine and I can move back and forth between the two screens. My problem comes when I create a new `Verse` and add it to the `Notebook`. Here is my code that lives in the second screen to create a new `Verse`:

```
realm.write(() => {
  let newVerse = realm.create('Verse', {
    reference: 'Genesis 1:1',
    favorite: false,
    memorized: false,
    scripture: 'My favorite verse'
  });

  if (this.notebook != null) {
    this.notebook.verses.push(newVerse);
  }
});
```

This is where my problem starts. At this point, if I select the back button to go back to the list of `Notebook`s, then select a notebook again, I get this error:

> Attempting to change value of a readonly property.
>
> Exception in native call
>                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Error calling RCTEventEmitter.receiveTouches
>
> at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:199)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
>   Caused by: com.facebook.jni.CppException: Exception calling object as function: TypeError: Attempting to change value of a readonly property.
>   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31) 
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:199) 
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

There are a couple of things I can do to make this problem go away, but both make my app useless. Since they might help in determining the issue though I can either remove `{notebook: notebook}` from `passProps` when I navigate to the new screen (but then nothing shows on the `Verse` list screen since it does not know which `Notebook` was selected). Or, I can not add the newly created `Verse` to the selected `Notebook` (but then I can't add data).

Since these two changes are in two different components (Realm and react-native-navigation), I'm not sure which component is the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects passed as props (`passProps`) are frozen by React Native.
Try changing:

```
passProps: {notebook: notebook}
```

to:

```
passProps: {notebook: _.cloneDeep(notebook)}
```

If you need to reflect changes to the `notebook` in the previous screen, I think you should do so through the store.

Another option is to pass `notebookId` and get the correct notebook by id from state.

Comment: I did not use `_.cloneDeep` but instead passed the primary key of the notebook and searched realm for that id. Everything is working great now. Thanks!